# How to make network interface changes permanent?

Tags: networking, server, internet, interface

I have this "script" on every startup(cron)[That is not working cause i have to login and its a headless server so i dont really log in to it.], how do i make these changes permanent?

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo ip addr flush dev enp2s0
sudo ip addr add 192.168.100.5/24 dev enp2s0
sudo ip link set enp2s0 up
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.100.1
```

I have created this but i does not work:

```
server@serverlaptop:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces 
auto enp2s0
    iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: What is the OS? For Ubuntu set it by netplan.

Comment: Ubuntu server 20.04.05 lts

Comment: https://netplan.io/

Comment: Thank you! It is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/etc/network/interfaces` mechanism is deprecated in all recent Ubuntu versions. Networking on servers is configured in netplan. I suggest that you delete the faulty file.

You will have a yaml file in `/etc/netplan`. I suggest that you amend it to:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.100.5/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.100.1]
      routes: 
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.100.1
```

After making this change, follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem.